# Best practice to protect model after post in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, parsing, http-post, data-protection

What is the best practice to protect model against unwanted parse/update after post in MVC3

Controller action called at HttpGet-> Product/Edit:

```
 public ActionResult Edit()
        {
          Product p = new Product();
          p.Id = 1;
          p.Name = "PC";
          Category cat = new Category();
          cat.Id = 1;
          cat.Name = "Non food";
          p.Category = cat;

          return View(p);
        }
```

This is the Edit View:

```
@model MvcApplication3.Models.Product
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Product", FormMethod.Post))
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="go" />
}
```

After the browser gets the response, the user inserts the following html segment into the page:

```
<input type="text" value="5" name="Category.Id" id="Category_Id"/>
```

He posts the form, and the following controller action gets the "Product" parameter.

```
    //
    // POST: /Class1/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Product p)
    {
      //Here: p.Company.Id is 5    !!!
      db.Save(p);
      return null;
    }
```

The problem is that the user should not be allowed to post/update the c.Company.Id.
I would not like to check the whole parameter structure hunting for unwanted values.
Im seeking for the best practice to solve the problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Bests,

Boolish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could separate the received entity type (i.e. the ViewModel) from the entity type persisted to the database, as described in [this recent blog post](http://freshbrewedcode.com/joshbush/2012/03/05/mass-assignment-aspnet-mvc/) by Josh Bush. Well worth a read - topical too as it stems from the recent similar problem experienced by GitHub.

e.g.

```
public ActionResult Edit(ProductModel p)
{
    // Map ProductModel -> a Product instance
    // Then save
}
```

Comment: Thank You for reply! I agree in that the view models are reasonable in a complex system case. If the view model requires aggregated/transformed data from the db model it should be reasonable as well ... etc. reasons.
But if Id like to create a quite simple system, just five to ten tables with the basic CRUD actions, it can be a huge effort to create several view models and bidirectional mapping (Automapper Ignor statements in db model to view model direction) "just" to protect the db model. ...

Comment: When the posted data arrives to the data binder, data binder creates a new ViewModel and fills the properties. (reflection)
Then I should read the db model and a "simmilar" model is created (same structure, except protected props at view model), and map the view model to db model. (By AutoMapper - reflection again. By hand it is not time effective.) ...

Comment: I thought some kind of...

Developer says somewhere/somehow:
- Whole db (the only one) model and all of its properties are protected.(eg: hardcoded rule)
- Protection exceptions depending on actual context. (eg: in session)
- Binding posted data directly into the db model (if it is possible, otherwise new model) according to the protection rules/exceptions. (reflection usage only once)

What is Your opinion?

Comment: @boolish.dev: "Just" to protect the model? Aren't that the most important aspect of programming? To protect the model? Your worries seems like premature optimization to me.

Comment: @jgauffin: Yes, this is one of the most important aspect of programming, that is why I wrote it between ""-s. I just wanted to solve the problem with the minimum effort.

Comment: AdaTheDev's and jgauffin's answers are equivalently appropriates but I can mark only one reply as answer. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

That's why you should use view models and not db entities in your views

http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/07/three-reasons-to-why-you-should-use-view-models/

Comment: Dear jgauffin, Thank You for your reply. Please see the comment I wrote to AdaTheDev's reply. Same question for you. What is your opinion?